# Can't import qtlottie in qml(PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qml, lottie

How can I install qtlottie qml module? I'm using and PyQt5(5.15.3) and as document says it's supported since 5.13 but when I try to import it I get the following error:

[image]

I found no workaround for it searching the internet... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get installed by default. In the Qt Maintenance Tool, you need to check the box labeled `Qt Lottie Animation`.

[image: Maintenance Tool]

Comment: Thansks for the answer, I turned it on but I found out I can't use custom Qt version with PyQT5 and so I can't choose the one I installed myself, What sould I do? is there any workaround?

Comment: Are you able to rebuild pyqt5 from source?

Comment: Yes, if I have to :)
P.S: I'm developing this app for rpi so I'll have to build it twice(once for my PC and once for RPI but if there is no other way, I will)